# Sorting and grouping

Tags: c#, sorting, grouping

I am working on the source code of a restaurant POS (Samba pos), and I have 2 problems how the output is formatted when printing a ticket.

The code below collects the tags of products, make headers of them, and sort the products below the header.

Problem 1: I have no influence in the order of headers so the output looks like:

**Main course**

Steak 22,50

**Drinks**

Cola 2,00

**Starters**

Soup 3,50

The right order should be Starters --> Main course --> Desserts --> Drinks
If I could sort the headers alphabetically I would be helped very much. I would change the group tags into:  1 Starters, 2 Maincourse etc etc

Problem 2:

The products are grouped in an earlier stage of the program. Due to choices of the programmer the grouping doesn't work well for me. I have a long list on the ticket like:

1 x Cola 2,00

2 x Cola 4,00

Is there a way to group products here so that I will have:

3 x cola 6,00

Here is the piece of code:

```
if (template.GroupTemplate.Contains("{PRODUCT TAG}"))
{
    var groups = lines.GroupBy(GetMenuItemTag);
    var result = new List<string>();
    foreach (var grp in groups)
    {
        var grpSep = template.GroupTemplate.Replace("{PRODUCT TAG}", grp.Key);
        result.AddRange(grpSep.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        result.AddRange(grp.SelectMany(x => FormatLines(template, x).Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have to sort `var groups`. The problem is that the text {PRODUCT TAG} is replaced with `grp.Key` within the loop, so ordering `var groups` before the loop probably won't work (do I need an extra loop?).

Adding the products to the headers is done on the 3 line of the loop. Is it possible to group items here?

I have dumped the whole file here:
http://pastebin.com/qFr5wN28

Edit:

This piece of code is for producing a ticket on a ticketprinter. A ticket would look like this:

```
BON
Datum: 2-2-2013
Tijd: 18:35    
Tafel nr.: B22    
Bon nr: 2    
------------------------------------------    
Breakfast    
- 1 Toast and Jam 1,50    
- 1 Egg, Bacon Cheese 3,99    
- 1 Toasted Bagel Cheese 2,25    
- 1 Toasted Bagel Jam 1,50    
- 2 Toast and Jam 1,50    
- 1 Egg, Bacon Cheese 3,99    
- 1 Bacon and Cheese 3,49    
- 1 Bacon and Tomato 3,49    
Deserts    
- 1 Rice Pudding 2,25    
- 1 Fruit Danish 1,50    
Main course    
- 1 Chicken Garden Wrap 5,25    
- 1 Chicken Caesar Wrap 5,75    
- 1 Canadian Wrap 6,99    
- 1 Chicken Greek Wrap 6,99
```

The headers are tags that I can add to products.
There are several things wrong: the headers above the articles (Deserts, Main Course) appear randomly. I would like to sort them. Not all articles are grouped, for example "toast and jam". If I could sort the headers, I would change the tags a bit. A desired output would be like this:

```
------------------------------------------    
1 Breakfast    
- 3 Toast and Jam 1,50    
- 2 Egg, Bacon Cheese 3,99    
- 1 Toasted Bagel Cheese 2,25    
- 1 Toasted Bagel Jam 1,50    
- 1 Bacon and Cheese 3,49    
- 1 Bacon and Tomato 3,49    
2 Main course    
- 1 Chicken Garden Wrap 5,25    
- 1 Chicken Caesar Wrap 5,75    
- 1 Canadian Wrap 6,99    
- 1 Chicken Greek Wrap 6,99    
3 Deserts    
- 1 Rice Pudding 2,25    
- 1 Fruit Danish 1,50
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what your issue, but you could add a `Select` when creating `groups` to create a new projection, if `grp.Key` is a problem.

Comment: The biggest problem is that I have no C# experience :-) The order of groups appearing on the tickets is random. This is very confusing. I must find a way to sort the groups, and the groups printed on the ticket appear in a logic way like: 1. starters 2. main courses 3. deserts etc.

Comment: You can easily order the groups using `OrderBy`. In order to give you more help it would be useful if you could edit your question with a very small sample of data which shows clearly what you want, and what your code above is currently doing.

Comment: I have added a ticket and a desired ticket. The autoformatter gave me a hard time :-)

Comment: I assume your headers are the `Key` from your call to `lines.GroupBy(GetMenuItemTag);`. To order these simply call `lines.GroupBy(GetMenuItemTag).OrderBy(l => l.Key)`.

Comment: YES!! that works perfectly. This is already a big step forward. Thank you!!! Do you have any consideration about the grouping?

Comment: You need to break down your question a little bit more for me. For get about all the formatting - it is very confusing to me given the amount of code involved. Just focus on `Courses` (the keys) and `Lines` (the values). So far you have been able to order your keys. What other issues are you facing. I will add an answer that can be bult on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order your lines using [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) like so:

```
var groups = lines.GroupBy(GetMenuItemTag).OrderBy(l => l.Key);
```

You also loop through the groups and amend the value of your key. This could be done by adding a `Select` projection to your group.

```
var groups = lines.GroupBy(GetMenuItemTag)
                  .Select(l => new { Key = template.GroupTemplate.Replace("{PRODUCT TAG}", grp.Key)
                                   , l.Value } )
                  .OrderBy(l => l.Key);
```

EDIT:

After thinking about this I realised I was being a little dumb yesterday. I think the following will help you:

```
//dummy data for testing purposes
List<Tuple<string, string>> items = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
items.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Dinner", "steak"));
items.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Dinner", "chicken"));
items.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Dinner", "chicken"));
items.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Desert", "chocolate"));

var groups = (from t in items
             group t by new {Course = t.Item1, Item = t.Item2}
             into grp
                 select new
                 {
                     grp.Key.Course,
                     grp.Key.Item,
                     Quantity = grp.Count()
                 })
             .OrderBy(g => g.Course);

foreach (var g in groups)
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", g.Course, g.Item, g.Quantity));
```

OUTPUT:

```
Dinner steak 1
Dinner chicken 2
Desert chocolate 1
```

Obviously you will need to modify the datatypes, etc, but the query itself should give you what you need.

Comment: first I want to say that I really appreciate your help! I will try to explain my problem a bit more. With the code you gave me I am able to influence the order of the group headers. A group contains now a header and products belonging to that header: softdrinks --> cola --> fanta What I want to archieve is that duplicate  products are added. So softdrinks --> 1 x cola 1,50 --> 1 x cola 1,50 becomes softdrinks --> 2 x cola 3,00

Comment: I believe you now need a second `GroupBy` on the values, which would then let you aggregate them and obtain a `Count`. Unfortunately I don't have VS on this machine so anything I tried would be a bit of a guess.

Comment: I think I will start a second topic about this. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @het.oosten I have edited my answer to give more info and hopefully answer the whole of your question.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I will see if I can find out which items var group contains.And go on from there.